# Узнать сколько время назад user был онлайн django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, надо чтоб у меня на сайте показывал сколько времени назад пользователь был онлайн как это можно реализовать вообще понять и не имею
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать готовый механизм или написать свой для решения задачи.

1. Готовый механизм - [django-online-users](https://github.com/lawrencemq/django-online-users)
2. Самостоятельное решение:

Нужно добавить поле `last_activity` в профиль пользователя (или переопределить имеющуюся модель пользователя). После, необходимо данное поле обновлять при каждом запросе пользователя. Это позволяет сделать собственный мидлвар.

**profiles/middleware.py**:

```
from django.utils import timezone

from myproject.profiles.models import Profile

class UpdateLastActivityMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user'), 'The UpdateLastActivityMiddleware requires authentication middleware to be installed.'
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            Profile.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id) \
                           .update(last_activity=timezone.now())
```

Добавим мидлвар в настройки:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # другие мидвары
    'myproject.profiles.middleware.UpdateLastActivityMiddleware',
)
```